# Review and experience with Rotman's Advanced modern algebra and Grillet's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am currently an undergraduate student, math major. I am studying abstract algebra, mostly selfstudy. I am using some basic books like Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian etc. Furthermore i am using abstract algebra by Dummit and foote as reference. Recently I saw three interesting books (at graduate level) : Abstract Algebra by Grillet, Advanced modern algebra part 1 by Rotman and Algebra a graduate course by Issac Martin.

I saw books and I felt Rotman's book is too fast and gives little view of groups, rings , fields etc.

On the other hand, Martin's book lacks in category theory. His book doesn't contain category theory. Moreover, I saw online reviews that this book is best for Algebrist. I is true?

When i saw Abstract Algebra by Grillet, this looks me interesting book because author uses category theory in goof amount, Homological Algebra and starts from basic undergraduate Algebra. The only thing book lacks is number of exercises. Grillet's book doesn't have many exercises as Rotman , Dummit and foote. Since this book looks me interesting in first view I wanted to read it.

**MY QUESTION**: Is the abstract algebra by grillet book is worthy? Is it suitable for me to use it as reference beside D&F abstract algebra? What are the prerequisites of the book? And in between Rotman's Advanced modern algebra and Grillet's Abstract Algebra which is good?

My background: I only had studied group theory yet ( up to permutation groups and little bit normal groups, iso(homo) morphisms) Thank you

Comment: People jump into categories way too quickly nowadays.  Having much more experience with algebraic/topological/geometric things is really crucial before understanding categories, else you have no idea of the motivating story.  What's the hurry?

Comment: @Randall I agree with you. To be honest, I am fond of advance stuff ( like : category theory, homological algebra, Algebraic Geometry etc) and I like to use fancy notation ( like in homological algebra). This is the reason, I hurry. I am sorry, my answer is really dumb but this is the reality. (Furthermore more collecting math books is my hobby I don't know this is good or not). I really appreciate if you give any advice to me.

Comment: Grillet's book is excellent and, I think, underappreciated. He does a nice job introducing the category theoretic concepts as you go, rather than just dumping it on you.

Comment: @blargoner Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate. Should I use the book as reference? In the hope it will not be painful for me.

Comment: You could also use Aluffi - Algebra Chapter 0

Comment: Grillet's book has many (perhaps too many) exercises. They are often lemmas accompanied with laconic phrases as "readers will enjoy proving these statements" or "readers may not groan"

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki That is really great. I will try to read the book. Thank you

Comment: @LukasHeger I have heard about this book alot. I will check it. Is it suitable for me? With only background in group theory?

Comment: @Afzal I'd say it's suitable for you.

Comment: @LukasHeger I will definitely read it. Thank you I appreciate.

Comment: @Afzal My comment was not really meant as a recommendation.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki please can you explain little bit why not recommending this book?

Comment: I read only parts and got the impression that it is just a huge collection of more or less related material without much excitement. Generally, I prefer shorter books on more specific topics (like Galois theory), where the proofs don't depend on the exercises.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki I understood. Thank you